# Would creating folders for each user be stressful or slow the server down?

Tags: linux, apache

I'm creating a site where users can upload and share their files.  I'm thinking about creating a folder for each individual user to upload their files. Would this slow the site down or cause trouble in the server?

I'm not expecting a million users, but around 100,00 - 200,000. Seems like a lot of folders for each user.

I also have another solution of just renaming the file when they upload, but I would like to keep the file name in tact so users still know which file is which.

Edit: if it helps I plan on using Linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the file system you are using. `ext2` uses linked list. So its slow for large number of files. `ext3` uses *hashed Binary trees*. Its much faster. Most server  has directory indexing turned on. So accessing 20k folders will not be that slow.

Problem is your users will grow. So its better you use a  nested directory structure than a single flat directory.

Comment: Thank you. Andy, your answer was great, but shiplu provided a more detailed answer. Thank you both for taking the time to answer this :)

Answer (score 1):

If you create 10,000 folders, then break up the tree so all the folders aren't all in the same directory.

If you have user "doug" and want to give him a folder, put it in `/d/o/doug`.